# Button inside RowDetailsTemplate in DataGrid - how to know which row clicked on?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have this XAML

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Reply" Name="btnReply" Click="btnReply_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Padding="10,0" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Subject}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Body}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

DataGrid bound to List
inside btnReply_Click I'd like to get instance of MyObject

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObject = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyObject;
```

Since the DataContext is inherited.